# TypeError: 'Value' object is not iterable : iterate around a Dataframe for prediction purpose with GCP Natural Language Model

Tags: pandas, loops, google-cloud-platform, typeerror

I'm trying to iterate over a dataframe in order to apply a predict function, which calls a Natural Language Model located on GCP. Here is the loop code :

```
        model = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

        barometre_df_processed = barometre_df
        barometre_df_processed['theme'] = ''
        barometre_df_processed['proba'] = ''
        print('DEBUT BOUCLE FOR')

        for ind in barometre_df.index:
            if barometre_df.verbatim[ind] is np.nan :  
                barometre_df_processed.theme[ind]="RAS"
                barometre_df_processed.proba[ind]="1"
            else:
                print(barometre_df.verbatim[ind])
                print(type(barometre_df.verbatim[ind]))
                res = get_prediction(file_path={'text_snippet': {'content': barometre_df.verbatim[ind]},'mime_type': 'text/plain'} },model_name=model)
                print(res)
                theme = res['displayNames']
                proba = res["classification"]["score"]
                barometre_df_processed.theme[ind]=theme
                barometre_df_processed.proba[ind]=proba
```

and the get_prediction function that I took from the Natural Language AI Documentation :

```
def get_prediction(file_path, model_name):
  options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='eu-automl.googleapis.com:443')
  prediction_client = automl_v1.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)
  payload = file_path
  # Uncomment the following line (and comment the above line) if want to predict on PDFs.
  # payload = pdf_payload(file_path)
  parameters_dict = {}
  params = json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())
  
  request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
  print("fonction prediction")
  print(request)
  return resultat[0]["displayName"], resultat[0]["classification"]["score"], resultat[1]["displayName"], resultat[1]["classification"]["score"], resultat[2]["displayName"], resultat[2]["classification"]["score"]
```

I'm doing a loop this way because I want each of my couple [displayNames, score] to create a new line on my final dataframe, to have something like this :

```
verbatim1, theme1, proba1
verbatim1, theme2, proba2
verbatim1, theme3, proba3
verbatim2, theme1, proba1
verbatim2, theme2, proba2
...
```

The if barometre_df.verbatim[ind] is np.nan is not causing problems, I just use it to deal with nans, don't take care of it.

The error that I have is this one :

```
TypeError: 'Value' object is not iterable
```

I guess the issues is about

```
res = get_prediction(file_path={'text_snippet': {'content': barometre_df.verbatim[ind]} },model_name=model)
```

but I can't figure what's goign wrong here.

I already try to remove

```
,'mime_type': 'text/plain'}
```

from my get_prediction parameters, but it doesn't change anything.

Does someone knows how to deal with this issue ?

Thank you already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not iterating correctly.
The way to iterate through a dataframe is:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['col1'])
```